# Javascript linking options to else if

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a little confused about why my code doesn't work. I'm very new and am extremely interested to know where I went wrong!
I want to times whichever option I choose by `var z` but can't get it to work.

This is my code so far:

```
<td><select>


  <option id="VAS" value="70">VAS</option>
  <option id="VTS" value="80">VTS</option>
  <option id="VAF" value="60">VAF</option>
  <option id="VGS" value="40">VGS</option>
  </select></td>
  <td>
   <input type="number" id="number" name="number">
  </td>
  <td>

<button onclick="myFunction()"> Total Value</button>
<br/>
<br/>


  <p id="value"></p>
  <script>
  function myFunction() {
  var y = document.getElementById("VAS").value;
  var z = document.getElementById("number").value;
  var a = document.getElementById("VGS").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("VAF").value;
  var d = document.getElementById("VTS").value;


  if (value == VGS) {
  var x = a * z;
  document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = x;
  }
  else if (value == VAS) {
  var x = y * z;
  document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = x;
  }




  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare the value of the select, not the values of the options. Here's how I fixed your JavaScript code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("VAS").parentNode.value);
    var z = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value);
    var x = a * z;
    document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Fully working demo:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("VAS").parentNode.value);
    var z = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value);
    var x = a * z;
    document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <select>


    <option id="VAS" value="70">VAS</option>
    <option id="VTS" value="80">VTS</option>
    <option id="VAF" value="60">VAF</option>
    <option id="VGS" value="40">VGS</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td>
  <input type="number" id="number" name="number">
</td>
<td>

  <button onclick="myFunction()"> Total Value</button>
  <br/>
  <br/>


  <p id="value"></p>
```

## EDIT:

To do this automatically, use `oninput` in the number field like so:

```
<input type="number" id="number" name="number" oninput="myFunction()" />
```

Demo:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("VAS").parentNode.value);
    var z = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value);
    var x = a * z;
    document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <select>


    <option id="VAS" value="70">VAS</option>
    <option id="VTS" value="80">VTS</option>
    <option id="VAF" value="60">VAF</option>
    <option id="VGS" value="40">VGS</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td>
  <input type="number" id="number" name="number" oninput="myFunction()">
</td>
<td>
  <br/>
  <br/>


  <p id="value"></p>
```

Comment: youre a life saver!

Comment: hey is there any chance you know how to update the number without having to use a button?

Comment: Sure, just use `oninput` in the number field. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your values are numbers, so value will never contain VAS. Furthermore, strings need to be surrounded by quotes, so your if-statement will look like this:

```
if(a == "VAS")
```

But the value contains numbers, so it should actually be:

```
if(a == "40")
```

Note: the values are all strings unless you cast them.

Comment: Can you update your code so we can see what you did?

Comment: if (value == "40") {
   var x = a * z;
    document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = x;
  }
   else if (value == "70") {
   var x = y * z;
    document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = x;
  }

Comment: So I'm not sure what exact variable you want to check (vars a, b, c, d, y or z), but value is not defined anywhere.

Comment: <option id="VAS" value="70">VAS</option> does this not count as a definition?